# SSMS :: Copy with Headers and paste to Excel results in more rows in destination

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms, export-to-excel

Peculiar issue: I have a table of `140.588` rows and `246,313` MB which looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DMA_assessment](
    [InstanceName] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [DatabaseName] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [SizeMB] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [ImpactedObjectName] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [ImpactDetail] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [AssessmentName] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [AssessmentNumber] [int] NULL,
    [SourceCompatibilityLevel] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [TargetCompatibilityLevel] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [TargetSQLServerEdition] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [Category] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Severity] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [ChangeCategory] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Impact] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Recommendation] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [MoreInfo] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [ObjectType] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [DBOwnerKey] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Click to enlarge.

[image]

This table was created by the [DMA Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15) and I want to use the output to visualize the results on Power BI. Querying a table so big is out of question. I need to export it in .csv or .xlsx file

If I do the notorious right click and "copy with Headers" and then I paste it on an Excel file the result has `141186` rows (-1 because the first rows are the columns names)

(Click again to see the details)

[image]

So here we are:

```
141186 - 140558 = 598
```

Where do they come from  those 598 rows?

I tried multiple times, the result is still the same.

Comment: Would any rows happen to contain newlines? Filter the first column for blanks. In general, copy-pasting from SSMS is not a terribly reliable way of transferring rows; SSMS has an import/export wizard that can push the results of any query to supported destinations, which includes CSV and Excel (though the latter possibly only old-style Excel with the 65K row limit, I'm not sure). I don't quite see as to why any of this would be necessary if you intend to have the results in PBI, though -- you say querying is "out of the question" but you're doing it yourself. Might as well skip the middle man.

Comment: Your data probably has some line breaks or something that is confusing the copy and paste. Personally, I would recommend you don't rely on SSMS to copy and paste data out of it apart from with the most simple of data. Use a different method or tool if you want to extract data from SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `varchar(max)` causes the problem. The size of a text field in Excel is limited. Following an example:

```
DECLARE @x VARCHAR(MAX) = '***************************************************************************';
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)
SELECT @x=CONCAT(@x,@x)

SELECT @x AS Test, 'Test' AS Test2
```

Copy the result to an excel file and you will get two rows, where the second column (Test2) is only featured in the second row.

Comment: Thank you @Tyron78, I changed all `varchar(max)` to `varchar(128)` but now when I paste I have `2.704.123` rows. So what should I do?

Comment: Whatever, your reply is good. I had to remove the columns and that's it. It's a bit brutal but I couldn't find any other solution. The problem was still there even when the columns were set to `varchar(50)`

Comment: Where did you change teh datatype? Directly in the mentioned table? Did you perform a substring on the varchar(max) values?

Comment: no, I brutally changed the data type through the designer. It truncated the values in the whole row.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using .dqy query in excel.

I develop SSMSBoost add-in and we have covered this in our article (you can create .dqy query directly in Excel, without our add-in):
https://www.ssmsboost.com/Features/ssms-add-in-run-query-in-excel

There is also a video, which explains 3 different ways of exporting the data into Excel without data loss (data type information is preserved):
(Copy-Paste in native excel format, XML export, .dqy Query)
https://youtu.be/waDCukeXeLU

Comment: `Copying failed. Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.`. I'm copy/pasting 223.896 rows

Comment: I believe there is a bug: 
1) Export to .xml file 2) Open the .xml file with Excel 3) Put a drop-down filter on every header 4) filter one header (in my case it was a NULL value) 5) you have now lister all rows that contains that NULL value in that column 6) Press again the drop-down menu and there is only the NULL option